# Mysql, очень долгие запросы

Tags: mysql, select

Есть таблица:

```
CREATE TABLE `log_site` (
`id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`date` DATETIME NOT NULL,
`ip` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
`agent` TEXT NOT NULL,
`http_referer` TEXT NOT NULL,
`request_url` TEXT NOT NULL,
`method` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`))COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2503081;
```

200 тыс строк

Запрос `SELECT ip, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM log_site AS t2 WHERE t2.ip = t1.ip) AS count_data FROM log_site AS t1 GROUP BY ip` выполняется 6 часов

Разбил на запросы по функциям в Python , выполнилось за 20 мин.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Настройки в my.conf дефолтные.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt,ip FROM log_site GROUP BY ip
```

для поля ip используйте индекс и поменяйте тип поля с VARCHAR на INT(10)Unsigned. Для преобразования используйте функции INET_ATON и INET_NTOA

Comment: Спасибо ваш работает быстро 0,3 сек. Но почему мой так долго работает, я понимаю что он дольше вашего отработать должен, но почему 6 часов, неужели он такой тяжелый?

Comment: ваш запрос некорректный, по сути двойная работа. почитайте как работает GROUP BY

Comment: 0.3 секунды это тоже много. Нужен индекс и преобразование типа